# What data is duplicated when MySQL/MariaDB BLOB columns are copied?

Tags: mysql, blob, mariadb, sql-insert, rdbms

Let `table_1` be created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_blob BLOB
);
```

Let `table_2` be created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_blob BLOB
);
```

What I want to know is, after I run this table-copying query

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (id, some_blob) SELECT id, some_blob FROM table_1;
```

will the actual text within each `some_blob` field of the `table_1` table be duplicated and stored on disk, or will the DB have only duplicated pointers to the disk locations containing the BLOB data?

One argument for why BLOB copying must involve the duplication of actual content reasons as follows:

> Duplication of BLOB content is necessary because changes to BLOB data in `table_1` should not also take place in `table_2`. If only the disk pointers were duplicated then content changes in one table would be reflected in the other table, which violates the properties of a correct copy operation.

Now I present an alternative method that the DB could implement to satisfy this copy operation. This alternative shows **the above argument is not necessarily true**. The DB could only duplicate disk pointers during the execution of the given `INSERT` statement, then whenever an `UPDATE` occurs which seeks to modify the BLOB data in one of the tables, the DB would only then allocate more space on disk to store the new data which is part of the `UPDATE` query. A BLOB data segment then is only deleted when there no longer exists any disk pointers to it, and a particular BLOB data segment could potentially have many disk pointers pointing to it.

So which of these strategies does MySQL/MariaDB use when executing the given `INSERT` statement, or does it use a different strategy?

**EDIT: Why I am asking this question**

Currently I am running a couple of `UPDATE` queries which are copying large amounts of BLOB data from one table to another in the same database (over 10 million rows of BLOB data). The queries have been running for a while. I am curious about whether the performance is so slow because some of the columns I am comparing are poorly indexed, because these queries are literally copying over the content instead of disk pointers, or perhaps because of both of these reasons.

I use an `INSERT` in the question's example because this simplifies the concept of database internals that I am trying to understand.

Comment: As far as I know, data is never shared between different tables. Each table corresponds to separate files or directories on disk.

Comment: For those who are down-voting the question, I would appreciate your thoughts on how this question could be improved or why you think it's inappropriate.

Comment: I think this can differ depending on which [database storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/storage-engines/) you use. The whole idea of using a database is so that you don't have to worry about these details. At least for as long as it doesn't have any real effect on performance. So, one thing your question should answer (I like this contradiction), is why do you want to know this?

Comment: [dba.se] would be a better place to ask questions about database implementation and optimization, it doesn't affect programming with the database.

Comment: Queries can be optimized to fit the database implementation, but I think you're right about this question being better suited for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, BLOBs aren't shared or pointed to. If you want to see what the bottleneck is - we'd need to see the queries, data volume, what you're doing, is it wrapped in a transaction for better I/O, did you use MySQL's `profiling` (that can tell you which part of the query takes up time) etc.

Comment: N.B. I remember hearing from someone that BLOBs are stored in tables as disk pointers. For example, that seems to be what is implied by the [MySQL BLOB Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html): 
"Each BLOB or TEXT value is represented internally by a separately allocated object. This is in contrast to all other data types, for which storage is allocated once per column when the table is opened."

Comment: @AjaxLeung that part from documentation, while true, doesn't mean that different tables will point to the same entry. It's used with indexes so that BLOB / TEXT data isn't stored in-memory with the index, it's being pointed to. It's good thinking on your side, but I'd bet that this is an I/O and bandwith issue.  Are you using a mechanical HDD or an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table has its own copy of the blob data, and of all other data.  MySQL doesn't do shallow copying of data. It's true that blobs are separately allocated objects, but they are not shared between tables. The description of the internals of the storage engine is provided so you can understand what's going on, not so that you can change it (unless you fork the storage engine source and create a new version ... but get your app working first).

So, your UPDATE queries are erasing old blob data and writing new. That's I/O intensive, and so it's probably slow.

Using INSERT as a way of simplifying your question is incorrect. Writing new blobs to a table is a faster process then overwriting existing ones.

Your best bet in production is to avoid UPDATEs to blob columns.

Comment: Good to know. I ended up cancelling my query after it was running for about 10 hours.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has _some_ optimizations in manipulating `TEXT`/`BLOB` columns.